# Saving JSON with PHP script leaves file blank

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm saving some JSON data to a JSON file using this PHP script:

```
<?php
$myFile = "json/countries.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST["data"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

And sending the data to the PHP script with this JS function:

```
saveJson(countries, '/save_countries_to_json.php');

function saveJson(object, file) {

$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    url: file,
    data: { data:object },
    success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
    failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
});
}
```

But the only thing that happens is that the JSON file I'm trying to save the data to is emptied.

If I change

```
data: { data:object },
```

to

```
data: { data:jQuery.parseJSON(object) },
```

I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A

What does the 'A' stand for?

If anyone knows what's wrong, please share your wisdom :)

Thanks!

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token is usually thrown when trying to parse JSON that is not formatted correctly. It can also happen when doing JSON.parse or alike. "A" in your case is probably the first letter in your JSON string? Check (console.log) your object twice before making ajax request. Try to pass it stringified (JSON.stringify(object)) also

Comment: I can't see that your PHP is returning any JSON

Comment: Also sanitise POSTed data yeah

Comment: encode the data first. json_encode($_POST["data"]).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php file

```
<?php
$myFile = "json/countries.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = urldecode($_POST["data"]);
$stringData1 = json_encode(json_decode($stringData));
fwrite($fh, $stringData1);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

Add this in your js file

```
saveJson(countries, '/save_countries_to_json.php');

function saveJson(object, file) {

$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    url: file,
    data: { data:object },
    success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
    failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
});
}
```

Comment: Well it's writing to the file but it's writing 'null' :)

Comment: Try this in your php
<?php

$myFile = "json/countries.json";
$data = json_encode($_POST["data"]);
file_put_contents($myFile, $data);
?>

Comment: Also dont forget to give write permissions to your countries.json