# Issue saving file with PHP script

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a PHP script for a JavaScipt site I've made.

The goal is to save the contents of a string as an HTML file when I click a button.

I'm using jQuery to make a Post request.

I'm using an Ubuntu OS with an Apache 2 server. The folder I'm writing to has permissions 777 (for testing only, will repeal this).

A requirement is the PHP must live in another file.

The issue is whenever I make the request, the file saves blank.

A requirement is each filename must be a timestamp. The file has the correct file name, but not contents.

So far, here is my code:

```
<?php

$fileName = $_GET['fileNameData'];
$htmlImport = $_GET['htmlToSaveData'];

$htmlToSave = (string)$htmlImport;

$myFile = fopen($fileName, "w") or die('You do not have write permissions');

//fwrite($myFile, $htmlToSave);
file_put_contents($myFile, $htmlToSave); 
fclose($myFile);

?>
```

I've tried the frwite function that I've commented out, same effect.

I have tested this in terminal by passing in arguments ($argv[1] and $argv[2]). That works fine.

The JS I've made to run my site looks like:

```
var newURL = 'saveHTML.php/?fileNameData=' + fileName + '&htmlToSaveData=' + htmlToSave
$.post(newURL)
    .done(function(){
        alert('Your file saved as ...' + htmlToSave)
    })
```

I've also tried this code, with the same result:

```
$.post('saveHTML.php/', {
    fileNameData : fileName,
    htmlToSaveData : htmlToSave
})
```

Both the fileName and htmlToSave are strings, although htmlToSave is rather long and is actually html text that I've converted to a string.

Does anyone have ideas about what's going on here? I'm not a PHP developer at all.

I'm using a callback so I can be sure I've collected all my html before I pass the string to PHP.

I've read and tested the recommendations on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932428/saving-json-with-php-script-leaves-file-blank) and this has been fruitless.

**EDIT** Don't be alarmed about the code, I realise it's a security issue but this is a learning project and this will not be in production.

Comment: As a test, try the following: `file_put_contents('./test.txt','test text');` If that fails you have a permission issue. If that works, you have a content or file path issue.

Comment: I gave that a shot so it must be a content issue

Answer (score 0):

I can see right off the bat that you have

```
$myFile = fopen($fileName, "w") or die('You do not have write permissions');

//fwrite($myFile, $htmlToSave);
file_put_contents($myFile, $htmlToSave); 
fclose($myFile);
```

`file_put_contents` takes a file name, not a handle.  So you would only need

```
file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlToSave);
```

Edit: I also feel like I should point out that you should not allow your users to name your files.  They could potentially do some nasty stuff to your machine.

Comment: OK, but as the question said, I've also tried ```fwrite($myFile, $htmlToSave); ``` and it's the same issue

Comment: if it is actually creating the file, like you mentioned but not putting in the contents.  What I posted above would be the reason for that.  The only other thing I can think of would be that $htmlToSave is null.  Also since you are using `$_GET`, only the `$.get` ajax request will work the `$.post` request would use the `$_POST` super global.  I would dump the contents of the `$htmlToSave` variable before you do your file writes to see what it contains. You can console log the return data from your server by modifying your `done` callback with `function(data) {console.log(data)}` .